# Extract numbers from text with regular expression

Tags: php, pcre

I am trying to extract `1` and `125` from this text with PHP:

```
preg_match("/^(?P<digit>\d+)/", "1 Foo ($125)",$m)
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you literally just want to match against that one single string (unlikely) or are you matching against a pattern (pretty much a requirement for a regexp). If the latter, what is that pattern?

Comment: i will need to extract from single string "1 Foo ($125)" like this thats all it can change like "2 Foo ($250)" so here i need to get 2 and 250 as two variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/\d+/', '1 Foo ($125) bar', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Note that I used preg_match_all which literally returns all matches in the pattern.